# Finding OWL Class in Java

Tags: java, owl

I'm starting to learn about OWL in Java, I've read some tuts including OWL API, Apache Jena, and Protege. I want to get the class in owl, but in OWL API it returns the inputted IRI.

Here's the process:
Let's take it that I'm looking for word 'beauty', which is individual of 'Inspector', and 'Inspector' is subclass of 'Guardian'.
Currently in my program the output is the IRI of beauty itself.
I wanted to get the Inspector IRI and Guardian IRI.

Any help/guide will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."  It's possible to suggest some general ways of doing what it sounds like you're trying to do, but without seeing your code, it's hard to say anything other than "your code must be wrong", which isn't very constructive. "Currently in my program the output is the IRI of beauty itself. I wanted to get the Inspector IRI and Guardian IRI."  Yup, sounds like the program isn't the one you want. :)

Comment: "I want to get the class in owl, but in OWL API it returns the inputted IRI."  Java is a statically typed language, so if you've got a method that has return type OWLClass, you're not actually returning an IRI from it;  the code wouldn't compile. Do you mean that you're _printing_ the result of something that you think should get an OWLClass and that you're _seeing_ an IRI?  That's probably  just be the way that toString is implemented for OWLClass.  Please show the code you're using, the output it actually generates, and the output that you expected (or wanted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an [OWLIndividual](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLIndividual.html), then you should be able to call [getTypes](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLIndividual.html#getTypes%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology%29) to get a set of the types that it has, one of which would be the class that you're describing. (Note that the default [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method some of the OWL API classes might show the IRI of the thing, so simply printing an  individual or class might look the same as printing its IRI as a string.)  [getTypes](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLIndividual.html#getTypes%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology%29) returns a set of [OWLClassExpressions](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClassExpression.html), and once you've got one of those, you could use [asOWLClass](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClassExpression.html#asOWLClass%28%29) to get the corresponding class, and then use [getSuperClasses](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClass.html#getSuperClasses%28org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology%29) to walk up your class hierarchy.  Note that, as [Ignazio pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518967/finding-owl-class-in-java/19520478#comment28969708_19520478), you should only call [asOWLClass](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClassExpression.html#asOWLClass%28%29) if the class expression is not anonymous.  To get a list of superclasses that is guaranteed to be complete, you'll also need to use reasoner that is complete with respect to OWL, which the reasoner built in with OWL API is not.

Comment: I would add the caveat that `asOWLClass()` can be called only if `isAnonymous()` returns false for that object, as mentioned in the [javadoc](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLClassExpression.html). Also, without an `OWLReasoner` the OWL API will not guarantee completeness of the results. A list of such reasoners is [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Reasoners,-OWL-API-Support,-papers-about-the-OWL-API).

Comment: Good point, and good catch!  I'm not much of an OWL API user;  I just know where to find the Javadocs, so I don't always catch all of those caveats.

Comment: nice mr joshua, thanks for your step by step description, now I'm able to find out what I wanted :)